# Understanding instability in a boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, boundary-value-problem

I am numerically solving the following boundary value problem:

$$
\begin{align}
y'_1 &= F(x)+x^2\rho(x) y_2\\
y'_2 &= -c\frac{\rho(x)}{x^2 P(x)}y_1
\end{align}
$$
with the boundary conditions $y_1(x=0)=y_1(x=1)=0$.

where $x$ is the independent variable, $\rho, P, F$ are functions of $x$, and $c$ is a positive constant.

I have solved this system of equations for a large number of combinations of $\rho, P, F$. I have come across a curious situation in which a tiny change to the independent variable $x$ results in a change of sign to the solutions $y_1,y_2$.

I am wondering if anyone has advice as to how I can go about understanding this apparent instability (and potentially remove it)?

Comment: How do you solve it numerically?

Comment: @ConvexHull I use [scipy.integrate.solve_bvp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html)